# Boost.Asio: Is it a good thing to use a `io_service` per connection/socket?

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, boost, boost-asio

I want to create an application that implements one-thread-per-connection model. But each connection must be stoppable. I have tried [this boost.asio example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/echo/blocking_tcp_echo_server.cpp) which implements the blocking version of what I want. But after a little bit questioning I've found out that there is no reliable way to stop the session of that example. So I've tried to implement my own. I had to use asynchronous functions. Since I want to make a thread to manage only one connection and there is no way to control which asynchronous job is employed to which thread, I decided to use `io_service` for each connection/socket/thread.

So is it a good approach, do you know a better approach?

My code is here so you can examine and review it:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/scoped_ptr.hpp>
#include <list>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <istream>

namespace ba = boost::asio;
namespace bs = boost::system;
namespace b  = boost;

typedef ba::ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor_type;
typedef ba::ip::tcp::socket socket_type;

const short PORT = 11235;
class Server;

// A connection has its own io_service and socket
class Connection {
protected:
    ba::io_service service;
    socket_type sock;
    b::thread *thread;
    ba::streambuf stream_buffer;    // for reading etc
    Server *server;
    void AsyncReadString() {
        ba::async_read_until(
            sock,
            stream_buffer,
            '\0',   // null-char is a delimiter
            b::bind(&Connection::ReadHandler, this,
                ba::placeholders::error,
                ba::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
    }
    void AsyncWriteString(const std::string &s) {
        std::string newstr = s + '\0';  // add a null char
        ba::async_write(
            sock,
            ba::buffer(newstr.c_str(), newstr.size()),
            b::bind(&Connection::WriteHandler, this,
                ba::placeholders::error,
                ba::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
    }
    virtual void Session() {
        AsyncReadString();
        service.run();  // run at last
    }
    std::string ExtractString() {
        std::istream is(&stream_buffer);
        std::string s;
        std::getline(is, s, '\0');
        return s;
    }
    virtual void ReadHandler(
        const bs::error_code &ec,
        std::size_t bytes_transferred) {
        if (!ec) {
            std::cout << (ExtractString() + "\n");
            std::cout.flush();
            AsyncReadString();  // read again
        }
        else {
            // do nothing, "this" will be deleted later
        }
    }
    virtual void WriteHandler(
        const bs::error_code &ec,
        std::size_t bytes_transferred) {
    }
public:
    Connection(Server *s) :
        service(),
        sock(service),
        server(s),
        thread(NULL)
    {  }
    socket_type& Socket() {
        return sock;
    }
    void Start() {
        if (thread) delete thread;
        thread = new b::thread(
            b::bind(&Connection::Session, this));
    }
    void Join() {
        if (thread) thread->join();
    }
    void Stop() {
        service.stop();
    }
    void KillMe();
    virtual ~Connection() {
    }
};

// a server also has its own io_service but it's only used for accepting
class Server {
public:
    std::list<Connection*> Connections;
protected:
    ba::io_service service;
    acceptor_type acc;
    b::thread *thread;
    virtual void AcceptHandler(const bs::error_code &ec) {
        if (!ec) {
            Connections.back()->Start();
            Connections.push_back(new Connection(this));
            acc.async_accept(
                Connections.back()->Socket(),
                b::bind(&Server::AcceptHandler,
                    this,
                    ba::placeholders::error));
        }
        else {
            // do nothing
            // since the new session will be deleted
            // automatically by the destructor
        }
    }
    virtual void ThreadFunc() {
        Connections.push_back(new Connection(this));
        acc.async_accept(
            Connections.back()->Socket(),
            b::bind(&Server::AcceptHandler,
                this,
                ba::placeholders::error));
        service.run();
    }
public:
    Server():
        service(),
        acc(service, ba::ip::tcp::endpoint(ba::ip::tcp::v4(), PORT)),
        thread(NULL)
    {  }
    void Start() {
        if (thread) delete thread;
        thread = new b::thread(
            b::bind(&Server::ThreadFunc, this));
    }
    void Stop() {
        service.stop();
    }
    void Join() {
        if (thread) thread->join();
    }
    void StopAllConnections() {
        for (auto c : Connections) {
            c->Stop();
        }
    }
    void JoinAllConnections() {
        for (auto c : Connections) {
            c->Join();
        }
    }
    void KillAllConnections() {
        for (auto c : Connections) {
            delete c;
        }
        Connections.clear();
    }
    void KillConnection(Connection *c) {
        Connections.remove(c);
        delete c;
    }
    virtual ~Server() {
        delete thread;
        // connection should be deleted by the user (?)
    }
};

void Connection::KillMe() {
    server->KillConnection(this);
}

int main() {
    try {
        Server s;
        s.Start();
        std::cin.get(); // wait for enter
        s.Stop();   // stop listening first
        s.StopAllConnections(); // interrupt ongoing connections
        s.Join();   // wait for server, should return immediately
        s.JoinAllConnections(); // wait for ongoing connections
        s.KillAllConnections(); // destroy connection objects
        // at the end of scope, Server will be destroyed
    }
    catch (std::exception &e) {
        std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Using an `io_service` object per connection is definitely a smell. Especially since you're also running each connection on a dedicated thread.

At this point you have to ask yourself what did asynchrony buy you? You can have all the code synchronous and have exactly the same number of threads etc.

Clearly you want to multiplex the connections onto a far smaller number of services. In practice there are a few sensible models like

1. a single `io_service` with a single service thread (this is usually good). No tasks queued on the service may ever block for significant time or the latency will suffer
2. a single `io_service` with a number of threads executing handlers. The number of threads in the pool should be enough to service the max. number of simultaneous CPU intensive tasks supported (or again, the latency will start to go up)
3. an io_service per thread, usually one thread per logical core and with thread affinity so that it "sticks" to that core. This can be ideal for cache locality

### UPDATE: Demo

Here's a demo that shows the idiomatic style using **option 1.** from above:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7ab9d4ac677df677)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/enable_shared_from_this.hpp>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <istream>
#include <list>
#include <string>

namespace ba = boost::asio;
namespace bs = boost::system;
namespace b  = boost;

typedef ba::ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor_type;
typedef ba::ip::tcp::socket   socket_type;

const short PORT = 11235;

// A connection has its own io_service and socket
class Connection : public b::enable_shared_from_this<Connection>
{
public:
    typedef boost::shared_ptr<Connection> Ptr;
protected:
    socket_type    sock;
    ba::streambuf  stream_buffer; // for reading etc
    std::string    message;

    void AsyncReadString() {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";

        ba::async_read_until(
            sock,
            stream_buffer,
            '\0',   // null-char is a delimiter
            b::bind(&Connection::ReadHandler, shared_from_this(),
                ba::placeholders::error,
                ba::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
    }
    void AsyncWriteString(const std::string &s) {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";

        message = s;

        ba::async_write(
            sock,
            ba::buffer(message.c_str(), message.size()+1),
            b::bind(&Connection::WriteHandler, shared_from_this(),
                ba::placeholders::error,
                ba::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
    }
    std::string ExtractString() {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";

        std::istream is(&stream_buffer);
        std::string s;
        std::getline(is, s, '\0');
        return s;
    }
    void ReadHandler(
        const bs::error_code &ec,
        std::size_t bytes_transferred) 
    {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";

        if (!ec) {
            std::cout << (ExtractString() + "\n");
            std::cout.flush();
            AsyncReadString();  // read again
        }
        else {
            // do nothing, "this" will be deleted later
        }
    }
    void WriteHandler(const bs::error_code &ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred) {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";
    }
public:
    Connection(ba::io_service& svc) : sock(svc) { }

    virtual ~Connection() {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";
    }

    socket_type& Socket() { return sock;          } 
    void Session()        { AsyncReadString();    } 
    void Stop()           { sock.cancel();        }
};

// a server also has its own io_service but it's only used for accepting
class Server {
public:
    std::list<boost::weak_ptr<Connection> > m_connections;
protected:
    ba::io_service _service;
    boost::optional<ba::io_service::work> _work;
    acceptor_type _acc;
    b::thread thread;

    void AcceptHandler(const bs::error_code &ec, Connection::Ptr accepted) {
        if (!ec) {
            accepted->Session();
            DoAccept();
        }
        else {
            // do nothing the new session will be deleted automatically by the
            // destructor
        }
    }

    void DoAccept() {
        auto newaccept = boost::make_shared<Connection>(_service);

        _acc.async_accept(
            newaccept->Socket(),
            b::bind(&Server::AcceptHandler,
                this,
                ba::placeholders::error,
                newaccept
            ));
    }

public:
    Server():
        _service(),
        _work(ba::io_service::work(_service)),
        _acc(_service, ba::ip::tcp::endpoint(ba::ip::tcp::v4(), PORT)),
        thread(b::bind(&ba::io_service::run, &_service))
    {  }

    ~Server() {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";
        Stop();
        _work.reset();
        if (thread.joinable()) thread.join();
    }

    void Start() {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";
        DoAccept();
    }

    void Stop() {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";
        _acc.cancel();
    }

    void StopAllConnections() {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";
        for (auto c : m_connections) {
            if (auto p = c.lock())
                p->Stop();
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    try {
        Server s;
        s.Start();

        std::cerr << "Shutdown in 2 seconds...\n";
        b::this_thread::sleep_for(b::chrono::seconds(2));

        std::cerr << "Stop accepting...\n";
        s.Stop();

        std::cerr << "Shutdown...\n";
        s.StopAllConnections(); // interrupt ongoing connections
    } // destructor of Server will join the service thread
    catch (std::exception &e) {
        std::cerr << __FUNCTION__ << ":" << __LINE__ << "\n";
        std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    std::cerr << "Byebye\n";
}
```

I modified the `main()` to run for 2 seconds without user intervention. This is so I can demo it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7ab9d4ac677df677)** (of course, it's limited w.r.t the number of client processes).

If you run it with a lot (a ***lot***) of clients, using e.g.

```
$ time (for a in {1..1000}; do (sleep 1.$RANDOM; echo -e "hello world $RANDOM\\0" | netcat localhost 11235)& done; wait)
```

You will find that the two second window handles them all:

```
$ ./test | sort | uniq -c | sort -n | tail
Shutdown in 2 seconds...
Shutdown...
Byebye
      2 hello world 28214
      2 hello world 4554
      2 hello world 6216
      2 hello world 7864
      2 hello world 9966
      2 void Server::Stop()
   1000 std::string Connection::ExtractString()
   1001 virtual Connection::~Connection()
   2000 void Connection::AsyncReadString()
   2000 void Connection::ReadHandler(const boost::system::error_code&, std::size_t)
```

If you really go berserk and raise `1000` to e.g. `100000` there, you'll get things similar to:

```
sehe@desktop:/tmp$ ./test | sort | uniq -c | sort -n | tail
Shutdown in 2 seconds...
Shutdown...
Byebye
      2 hello world 5483
      2 hello world 579
      2 hello world 5865
      2 hello world 938
      2 void Server::Stop()
      3 hello world 9613
   1741 std::string Connection::ExtractString()
   1742 virtual Connection::~Connection()
   3482 void Connection::AsyncReadString()
   3482 void Connection::ReadHandler(const boost::system::error_code&, std::size_t)
```

On repeated 2-second runs of the server.

Comment: Asynchronous operations has given me the advantage of being able to stop those dedicated threads. I cannot do this if I use synchronous operations.

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.tutorial.interruption. Also, that has **zero** relation with the number of threads or service objects. You can still do the same with a single service/thread.

Comment: @jnbrq I've added a demo using _option 1._ (a single io service on a singel thread) and it will handsomely handle thousands of concurrent requests asynchronously, until stopped from the main thread. I hope this sample helps demonstrate some Asio idioms

Comment: The livestream recording is here: [starting ~18:15](https://www.livecoding.tv/video/boost-asio-multiplexing-async-sessions-1/) ([experiment](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/10?m=24182469#24182469)) (and the remaining part [here](https://www.livecoding.tv/video/boost-asio-multiplexing-async-sessions-2/))

Comment: Your `AsyncWriteString()` function creates a local variable and then passes it to `async_write()`. The string is destroyed when the function exits but the buffer is required to be valid until the write handler is called. This is a bug. Also, there is no need to add a null character -- Just use `s.c_str()` and `s.size() + 1` because `std::string::c_str()` provides an additional null character for you.

Comment: So it's very nice. But is it possible to use thread-per-connection model? Since I want to handle many operations so using only one thread may not be enough.

Comment: And could you explain me why did you use `boost::weak_ptr` for connections?

Comment: @janm well spotted, [fixed](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7ab9d4ac677df677) (the code was unused, so I didn't notice)

Comment: @jnbrq 1 thread per connection is such a bad idea that I won't demo it. (How do you think it will handle these 1000 connections?) You can ask for any of the options, but really you should not complicate things unless you have to. Why do you think you need this?

Comment: @jnbrq The weak ptrs are mainly there to show you that you can connections cleanup themselves. Honestly, I don't know why you even need the list of connections. You'll notice that you can stop the work just as easily without that. (IOW it was just another side of idiomatic session handling in Asio)

Comment: @sehe Yes, you're right. I think I should keep going with your solution. Your good solution is pretty enough for me. :) Thank you all. :)