# C++: Boost.Asio: Start SSL Server session in a new thread

Tags: c++, session, boost, boost-asio, stdthread

I wrote a pair of server/client programs based on [this example for the server](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/ssl/server.cpp) and I'm done of all communication protocols. The server is supposed to receive multiple connections from multiple connections from multiple client, so I want to separate the sessions from each other, and I'm hoping I could do that with `std::thread`.

This looks to be easy, but I don't know how to do it at all. All examples online seem to show how to run a function in parallel, but it doesn't seem to show how to create an object in a new thread.

I've put some comments to explain my understanding for this session mechanism.

The code I wanna use is the following:

```
class server
{
public:
  server(boost::asio::io_service& io_service, unsigned short port)
    : io_service_(io_service),
      acceptor_(io_service,
          boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), port)),
      context_(io_service, boost::asio::ssl::context::sslv23)
  {
    //some code...


    //notice the next lines here create the session object, and then recurs that to receive more connections
    session* new_session = new session(io_service_, context_);

    //this is called to accept more connections if available, the callback function is called with start() to start the session
    acceptor_.async_accept(new_session->socket(),
        boost::bind(&server::handle_accept, this, new_session,
          boost::asio::placeholders::error));
  }

  void handle_accept(session* new_session, const boost::system::error_code& error)
  {
    if (!error)
    {
      //so the session starts here, and another object is created waiting for another session
      new_session->start();
      new_session = new session(io_service_, context_);
      //now this function is, again, a call back function to make use of new_session, the new object that's waiting for a connection
      acceptor_.async_accept(new_session->socket(),
          boost::bind(&server::handle_accept, this, new_session,
            boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }
    else
    {
      delete new_session;
    }
  }

private:
  boost::asio::io_service& io_service_;
  boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor_;
  boost::asio::ssl::context context_;
};
```

How can I create these sessions in new `std::thread`?

If you require any additional information, please ask. Thanks.

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31486010/boost-asio-is-it-a-good-thing-to-use-a-io-service-per-connection-socket/31486112#31486112

Comment: @sehe Thank you for the response. Apparently the model I'd like to do is option 2. I need this because I'm gonna get many connections from about 10+ clients. If I undertstand the code of option 1 correctly, then the connection class is equivalent to the session class here. Right? Is there a sample for option 2 code with std::thread or boost::thread?

Comment: @sehe Thank you. Just to be sure if I understand option 2, it should start a new thread for every client, right? That's what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Oh god. No! See the comments at that linked answer :)

Comment: @sehe Thank you, and sorry I didn't notice the comments (seems I'm not the first one to think about this solution ^_^). I'm too ignorant in the details of this and would like to learn more. My program is gonna get many connections, and I wanna make many threads to avoid blocking as much as possible. If you, as a pro, think that option 2 is the best option, then I'll listen to you. I'd be really grateful for an example. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've reworked the example for the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31486010/boost-asio-is-it-a-good-thing-to-use-a-io-service-per-connection-socket/31486112#31486112) mixed with your sample code.

It demonstrates the same principle but running the io_service on as many threads as your hardware has support for (i.e. `thread::hardware_concurrency`).

The catch here is

- (shared) object lifetimes
- thread safety

Most Asio objects are not thread-safe. Therefore you need synchronize access to them. Old fashioned mutual exclusion (`std::mutex` etc.) don't work well in this scenario (because you really don't want to lock on every completion handler and you *reeeeeeally* don't want to hold a lock across asynchronous calls ¹.

Boost Asio has the concept of `strand`s for this situation:

- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service__strand.html
- [Why do I need strand per connection when using boost::asio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12794107/why-do-i-need-strand-per-connection-when-using-boostasio/12801042#12801042)

I elected the simplest solution to make all operations on a "socket" (ssl stream/connection/session or however you would refer to this logically) on a strand.

And besides that I made all the access to `acceptor_` serialized on its own strand.

> *A hybrid solution might move all the connections on a `io_service`+pool and keep the listener (`Server`) on a separate `io_service` which could then be it's own implicit strand*

**Note**: About the shutdown sequence:

- I made the destruction of `Server` explicit so we can stop the `acceptor_` on its `strand`(!!) as required.
- The `pool` threads will not complete until all connections have been closed. If you want control over this, see the linked answer again (which shows how to keep weak pointers tracking the connections). Alternatively, you can accompany all the asynchronous operations in the session with timeouts and check the `Server` for shutdown signal.

### Demo Code

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0f8d26fa2ac34142)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ssl.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/enable_shared_from_this.hpp>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <istream>
#include <list>
#include <string>

namespace bs  = boost::system;
namespace ba  = boost::asio;
namespace bas = ba::ssl;

using ba::ip::tcp;
using SslContext = boost::shared_ptr<bas::context>;

typedef ba::ip::tcp::acceptor    acceptor_type;
typedef bas::stream<tcp::socket> stream_type;

const short PORT = 26767;

class Session : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<Session>
{
public:
    typedef boost::shared_ptr<Session> Ptr;

    Session(ba::io_service& svc, SslContext ctx) : strand_(svc), ctx_(ctx), stream(svc, *ctx) { }

    virtual ~Session() {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";
    }

    stream_type::lowest_layer_type& socket() { return stream.lowest_layer(); } 
    void start()                             { AsyncReadString();          } 
    void Stop()                              { stream.shutdown();            } 

protected:
    ba::io_service::strand strand_;
    SslContext             ctx_;
    stream_type            stream;
    ba::streambuf          stream_buffer;
    std::string            message;

    void AsyncReadString() {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";

        ba::async_read_until(
            stream,
            stream_buffer,
            '\0', // null-char is a delimiter
            strand_.wrap(
                boost::bind(&Session::ReadHandler, shared_from_this(),
                    ba::placeholders::error,
                    ba::placeholders::bytes_transferred)));
    }
    void AsyncWriteString(const std::string &s) {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";

        message = s;

        ba::async_write(
            stream,
            ba::buffer(message.c_str(), message.size()+1),
            strand_.wrap(
                boost::bind(&Session::WriteHandler, shared_from_this(),
                         ba::placeholders::error,
                         ba::placeholders::bytes_transferred)));
    }

    std::string ExtractString() {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";

        std::istream is(&stream_buffer);
        std::string s;
        std::getline(is, s, '\0');
        return s;
    }

    void ReadHandler(const bs::error_code &ec, std::size_t /*bytes_transferred*/) 
    {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";

        if (!ec) {
            std::cout << (ExtractString() + "\n");
            std::cout.flush();
            AsyncReadString();  // read again
        }
        else {
            // do nothing, "this" will be deleted later
        }
    }

    void WriteHandler(const bs::error_code &/*ec*/, std::size_t /*bytes_transferred*/) {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";
    }
};

class Server : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<Server>
{
  public:
    Server(ba::io_service& io_service, unsigned short port) :
        strand_  (io_service),
        acceptor_(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), port)),
        context_ (boost::make_shared<bas::context>(io_service, bas::context::sslv23))
    {
        //
    }

    void start_accept() {
        auto new_session = boost::make_shared<Session>(strand_.get_io_service(), context_);

        acceptor_.async_accept(new_session->socket(),
                strand_.wrap(boost::bind(&Server::handle_accept, this, new_session, ba::placeholders::error)));
    }

    void stop_accept() {
        auto keep = shared_from_this();
        strand_.post([keep] { keep->acceptor_.close(); });
    }

    void handle_accept(Session::Ptr new_session, const bs::error_code& error)
    {
        if (!error) {
            new_session->start();
            start_accept(); // uses `acceptor_` safely because of the strand_
        }
    }

    ~Server() {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";
    }

  private:
    ba::io_service::strand strand_;
    tcp::acceptor          acceptor_;
    SslContext             context_;
};

int main() {
    ba::io_service svc;
    boost::thread_group pool;

    {
        auto s = boost::make_shared<Server>(svc, PORT);
        s->start_accept();

        for (auto i = 0u; i<boost::thread::hardware_concurrency(); ++i)
            pool.create_thread([&]{svc.run();});

        std::cerr << "Shutdown in 10 seconds...\n";
        boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::seconds(10)); // auto-shutdown in 10s

        std::cerr << "Shutdown...\n";
    } // destructor of Server // TODO thread-safe

    pool.join_all();
}
```

Which prints

```
$ (for a in {1..20000}; do (sleep 1.$RANDOM; echo -e "hello world $RANDOM\\0" | netcat localhost 6767)& done)

$ time ./test | sort | uniq -c | sort -n | tail
Shutdown in 10 seconds...
Shutdown...
      1 Server::~Server()
      1 void Session::AsyncReadString()virtual Session::~Session()
      1 void Session::AsyncReadString()void Session::ReadHandler(const boost::system::error_code&, std::size_t)
      1 void Session::ReadHandler(const boost::system::error_code&, std::size_t)void Session::AsyncReadString()
      3 
   4523 void Session::AsyncReadString()
   4524 void Session::ReadHandler(const boost::system::error_code&, std::size_t)
   4526 virtual Session::~Session()

real    0m10.128s
user    0m0.430s
sys 0m0.262s
```

---

¹ The whole point of asynchrony is to avoid blocking on IO operations that may take "longer". And the idea of locking is to never hold locks for "longer" amounts of time or they will kill scalability

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm very grateful. It's 1 AM here, I'll sleep on it, and I'll start implementing tomorrow. See you!

Comment: The recorded live session (3 vids) has been added to [Asio playlist](https://www.livecoding.tv/video/sehe/playlists/boost-asio-multiplexing-async-sessions/) here.

Comment: I have a question. I noticed that at every read and write call in the session you instantiate a new `shared_from_this()`, i.e., a `shared_ptr()` object. Isn't this somehow not efficient? Is there a better way to do this so that not a new instance is created at every call?

Comment: You are free to create a pool of session objects if you think that is more efficient in your application. However, you will still have manage the lifetimes so that the session object stays alive. Since it's not _generally_ possible to know in advance how many sessions you are going to have, this depends on your particular application. Also, think of how you would garbage collect unused session instances (if at all). @TheQuantumPhysicist

Comment: I see. Thanks for explaining!

Comment: Thank you chaps. Much appreciated.